# Width of an absolutely positioned div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have following `HTML`:

```
<div class="outter">
    <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id quis animi nulla accusantium minus, similique quos ullam consectetur neque voluptatibus odio, ipsam cumque consequuntur dolorem harum nostrum sequi dolores! Ut.</div>
</div>
```

And this `CSS`:

```
.outter {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 100px;    
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    left: -100px;
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

And here is the [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/gL29b54a/).

The inner `div` should take its text content width upto `400px` maximum (should be fluid). With this code it takes its parent's width.

How do achieve this?

**UPDATE**

This inner div text can be changed dynamically

Comment: Demo link doesn't show much...

Comment: @Eraph Sorry it was a wrong link. :) updated

Comment: your question is not clear..

Comment: in outer div width & height both are 100px, which is smaller than the max-width 400px of inner div. question is not clear. can you tell what actually you want to achieve in detail :)

Comment: @Faizan you can clarify it at least by 50% by changing `background: green` to `background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .5)`

Comment: I understand what you are asking but essentially this is not possible with an absolutely postioned element. If you could clarify what it is you actually trying to so and why, we might be able to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

When using `max-width` put explicit width first

```css
.outter {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100px;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    left: -100px;
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .5);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
    <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id quis animi nulla accusantium minus, similique quos ullam consectetur neque voluptatibus odio, ipsam cumque consequuntur dolorem harum nostrum sequi dolores! Ut.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :) Lets say the width of inner div's text content is 150px. then the inner div should take the text content's width. This text can be changed dynamically

Comment: @samNo1 you know, you have a very strange markup. But check this out https://jsfiddle.net/v32kkav6/ Notice negative `margin-right`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, **an element with absolute positioning doesn't take any width by default, only the size of its content**.

So, if a block element should have a 100% width as default, you have to set it for an element with `position absolute`.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve there, but you should simply set the width property you "lost" with position absolute :

```
.inner {
    position: absolute; // here, width becomes "auto"
    top: -60px;
    left: -100px;
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .5);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%; // 100% = closest relative parent width, set it to whatever you want
    max-width: 400px;
}
```